# Thickness of a pencil, width of a dime, or as thick as a human hair

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, measuring-units

If a person wants to describe the dimensions of something to someone, they'll often relate the measurement of a thing to the size of an everyday household object.

Examples:

- It's the thickness of a pencil
- It's about the width of a dime
- It's as thick as a human hair

---

I would like to find a standard/common list of examples, like the ones I mentioned above, but I don't know what such a thing would be called.

Is there a word for a household object that is used to describe the size of something?

Comment: It is sometimes called a [**simile**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/simile). For example *It's as light as a feather*.

Comment: You could call the thickness of a human hair or pencil a unit of comparison, or, as Wikipedia says, an 'informal unit of measurement'. In Britain we have 'an area the size of Wales', and 'the size of a London bus' among other units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Harvey commented, the thickness of a human hair or of a pencil is a unit of comparison (although I could find no reference in Wikipedia to an 'informal unit of measurement'). In Britain, 'an area the size of Wales' and 'the size of a London bus', among others, are common informal units of measurement.

You will find other such units here, [List of unusual units of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement), and here, [List of humorous units of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_humorous_units_of_measurement).